# Angular 6 Bootstrap not found in ./src/.././src/app/app.browser.module.ts

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I'm sorry for my bad english.
my fault is that when I want to seo the joints in the module.browser class bootstrap does not appear

app.browser.module.ts;

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @NgModule({

        bootstrap: [
            AppComponent
        ],

        imports:[

            BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'app-root'}),


            AppModule,

        ]
    })
    export class AppBrowserModule {}
```

my bad eror

```
D:\çalışmalar\code\myWebSite>ng add @ng-toolkit/universal
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
INFO: Project property is set to 'myWebSite'.
ERROR: Bootstrap not found in ./src/.././src/app/app.browser.module.ts.
ERROR: If you think that this error shouldn't occur, please fill up bug report here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/new
INFO: stacktrace has been sent to tracking system.
Nothing to be done.
```

help me please

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running once `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal` we got our initial files generated and retrieved this error.

For me this solution worked:

1. Delete app.browser.module.ts
2. In main.ts you need to insert AppModule (instead of AppBrowserModule) in the .bootstrapModule() function.

Now your main.ts looks like this:

```
import { AppBrowserModule } from '.././src/app/app.browser.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                    platformBrowserDynamic()
                      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
                      .catch(err => console.log(err));
                  });
```

3. Add `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` to your app.module.ts @NgModule configuration
4. Run `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal`
5. This will run through successfully but ng-toolkit will leave an invalid line in app.module.ts `.withServerTransition({appId:''}),` which you can simply delete. Afterwards you can run `ng run build:prod` and deploy.
6. If this retrieved an error check if `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` exists in your app.module.ts and run `ng run build:prod` again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check where you included Bootstrap.

ERROR: Bootstrap not found in ./src/.././src/app/app.browser.module.ts.

This error points that, it can not find the right path.